# If someone says, "I behoove you to read the policies" is that a correct use of the word?

Tags: grammar

I was attending a presentation and the  manager said at least ten times, "I behoove you to read the policies. The first time I heard it, I thought I had not heard it correctly. But then he said it again and again and the audience was primarily educators. It did not sound like the correct use of the word.  I have only heard it used in a sentence, "It would behoove you to read the policies."

Comment: See here: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/behoove

Comment: The speaker probably meant [beseech](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beseech), in the sense of earnestly request, then mispoke or confused the two words.

Comment: I have had managers like this.

Comment: Might be worth commenting that in BrE the word is *behove* (which can be pronounced *behoove* but isn't usually). *Behoove* looks really odd this side of the pond.

Comment: There is nothing wrong or unusual about *behoove* in the indicative mood. https://books.google.com/books?id=ITR5AAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA495&dq=%22i%20behoove%22&pg=PA495#v=onepage&q=%22i%20behoove%22&f=false . https://books.google.com/books?id=ITR5AAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA495&dq=%22i%20behoove%22&pg=PA496#v=onepage&q=%22i%20behoove%22&f=false

Comment: It is, however, quite rare in practice. It barely makes the Google N-Grams lower cutoff for graph results.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're right. This manager should say:

> "It would behoove you to read the policies" or 
>   "It behooves you to read the policies."

**[behoove](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/behoove)**

> *transitive verb*
>   : to be necessary, proper, or advantageous for
>    - *it behooves us to go*
>
> *intransitive verb*
>   : to be necessary, fit, or proper
>
> [Source: Merriam-Webster Dictionary]

Comment: Hi Mahmoud, congrats on your first answer on our site! Well done on providing a link to a dictionary definition, but we much prefer answers to include the relevant information from that link, rather than force other users to leave our site to find out what the link offers. I've [edit]ed your answer to show one way that this might be presented. Note that answers presented like this are much more likely to receive upvotes, whereas bare links can often attract downvotes. For further guidance, see [answer]. I look forward to your next contribution! :-)